# Can MSAL.Net be used for RPOC flow to get the Id token in Azure B2C

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Based on the documentation in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga
I can use PostMan and get an access_token, id_token and refresh_token.  I have this working perfectly.  I have tried to use MSAL.Net to do the exact same operation and I get the error mesage

> API does not accept client id as a user-provided scope
> this occurs when I include the clientid in the scopes.

If I do not include the client id in the scopes then I get

> The scope 'openid offline_access profile' provided in request must specify a resource, such as 'https://example.com/calendar.read'.

Am I doing something incorrect or is this simply not supported in MSAL.Net.
All I really need are the claims from the id_token or access_token so I can create a ClaimsIdentity and call

```
           AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = false,
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = new DateTimeOffset(securityToken.ValidFrom),
            ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(securityToken.ValidTo)
        }, identity);
```

I am using AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword for the MSAL call.

Comment: Not sure its related the to scope that you're using. So check the scope that you're using?

Comment: Are you trying to use `AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword( IEnumerable<string> scopes, string username, SecureString password)` to get the token?

Comment: Yes the id_token and the access_token

Comment: @bmukes Can you share the full request (including the `scope`) in Postman? Remember to remove the client id, client secret, username and password.